# Single Responsibility Principle for class of type GameManager

Tags: java, oop

I was wondering how would someone justify creating a GameManager while having the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) in mind. concrete example: GameManager of a memory game (with the cards that you have to match). It obviously have many responsibilities: tracking of who's turn is it, switching between the turns, tracking when the game is finished, who the winner is and more...

Answer (score 3):

When in doubt about exceeding object responsabilities. There is a concept related to SRP, [cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29), which is quite objective. In [Konamiman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23076173/861763), the GameManager is 100% cohesive. It means all dependencies (instance fields) are used in all public methods.

0% would be the opposite:

```
class GameManager {
   private int anInt;
   private object aObj;

   public void Foo() {
         // Do anything but using anInt or aObj
   }
}
```

If you find several cohesive components inside your object:

```
class GameManager {
    private T1 obj1;
    private T2 obj2;

    public void Foo() {
       T1.F1();
    }

    public void Goo() {
       T2.G1();
    }
}
```

The class should be split in two:

```
class GameManagerFoo {
    private T1 obj1;

    public void Foo() {
       T1.F1();
    }
}
class GameManagerGoo {

    public void Goo() {
       T2.G1();
    }
}
```

Nice point @Jackl56: About property setters and getters you have 2 options. You could not take them into account or you could consider they lower your cohesion but to an acceptable level.

Comment: Nice idea. But what about a Car which has different properties, for example color, and number of wheels. then I would have properties (get/set) methods that only operate on a subset of the class member variables. or thinking about it again, those are not dependencies. so when you say dependencies you are speaking of member variables that are references to other classes. is it correct to state it this way?

Answer (score 2):

The key is that if you do things properly, the GameManager class will not **directly** have all the responsibilities you have mentioned. Instead, it will delegate these responsibilities into other classes, that will be passed to it by using some form of dependency injection. So you can say that the GameManager class has a single responsibility: to coordinate the work of the other classes; and has one single reason to change: to accommodate a change in the game logic that requires a new class to participate or to change the order of the interaction between classes.

A very simple example (sorry, C# syntax, but you get the idea):

```
public class GameManager
{
    //constructor - note that the parameter types are interfaces, not classes
    public GameManager(
        IPlayerManager playerManager,
        ITurnManager turnManager)
    {
        this.playerManager = playerManager;
        this.turnManager = turnManager;
    }

    public void DoNextTurn()
    {
        var nextPlayer = playerManager.GetNextPlayer();
        turnManager.ProcessTurn(nextPlayer);
        //etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: I like it. follow-up question for this kind of design: would you always go with interfaces (IPlayerManager, ITurnManager) or at some cases you might say that it's ok to program to an implementation, given that it's not likely to ever change. In other words I am questioning the need for abstraction. (otherwise we will likely to have through-out the entire lifecycle of the program one class per interface relationship and this seems redundant)

Comment: @Jackl56 Your code should ALWAYS depend on implementations, never on concrete classes. Otherwise you will end up having tightly coupled code that will not be testable. Take a look here: http://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code

Comment: I have read the link. very useful. So I understand that it will not be as easily tested, but leaving testability aside, what's wrong with programming to concrete classes? I agree this would make tight coupling between those classes but what's the wrong in that? (other than testability)

Comment: What's wrong with drowning, leaving aside the fact that you can't breathe? :-) Don't underestimate testability, it is a critical feature that your code must have at any cost.